# Work on two branches of the same repository at once

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

I recently started working on a different branch of my repository, but I noticed that I had not merged my work from an earlier branch yet. I figured I could copy and paste the missing pieces over from one branch to the other but I'm not sure if I can open them in parallel in two separate instances of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can still merge your previous branch into the one you are working on?
If you really really need to have both versions open at the same time, you could clone the same repository into another, seperate, folder and have the previous branch there and open that version of the project.

Comment: I'll go the safe route and try cloning the other branch in a separate folder. This won't cause any conflicts between the branches, right?

Comment: I don't trust my own git skills enough to do anything too complicated as I'm still learning and I've seen first hand how some mistakes can come with devastating consequences which I'd rather avoid.

Comment: I will cause conflict only the same way it would cause conflict if two people are editing the same file and then push it. So, as long as you only commit/push different files between the branches, you should be fine. There is also something called Git Worktree, that i'm not familiar enough with to explain it. Might be a bit more complex but you could take a look at it. I believe it also does what you want.